# Issue in Forwarding Email?

Tags: html, salesforce, html-email

I have created one HTML Template in Sales force. When i am testing the email template which is working perfect.but when i am forwarding the same email to another person the receiver getting HTML data as per created in Sales force. Can you please suggest the solution.

Comment: Do you mean the forwarded email has details from the original sender? That is how its supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding a mail, will alway screw up your html and css.
The best way is to either sent the mail directly to the personer, or what I normally do, sent the mail as an attachment to a new mail. Then the code will look fine.